# jquery-ui autocomplete change event ui.item always null

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jquery 1.9.1 and jquery-ui 1.10.1.

I have a json data source coming from PHP code that pulls data from a MySQL database. The data is encoded using json_encode and comes out in the following format:

```
[{"label":"label1","value":"value1"},{"label":"label2","value":"value2"},...]
```

The *select* event works fine and the *ui.item* argument contains the correct information when I select an item from the autocomplete menu but, in the *change (autocompletechange)* event, the *ui.item* argument is always *null*.

```
  $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({ source: 'custSearch.php',
                                      select: function(event, ui) {
                                            console.log(ui);
                                            $( "#customer" ).text(ui.item.label);
                                            $("#validpic").remove();
                                            $("#validpic_div").append("<img id='validpic' src='/images/icons/001_06.png'>");
                                            $( "#go" ).focus();
                                          },
                                       change: function(event, ui) {
                                            console.log(ui);
                                          }
                               });
```

Again, in the code above, the *select*  *ui.item*  holds a label and value pair from the json data source. However, the *change*  *ui.item* is always null, even when a selection has been made.

From the jquery-ui autocomplete api documentation, *ui.item* should be:

> The item selected from the menu, if any. Otherwise the property is null.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yvakc/

Comment: Okay, that's with a static data source. Could a dynamic data source cause this not to work?

Comment: well, [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StrubT/yvakc/1/) uses a more or less dynamic data source and works as well

Comment: The problem was the $("#go").focus() code. When I remove that code, all works. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: j08691 doesn't work when pressing "Enter" key instead of mouse click